# How to describe the specific circle that is formed by an intersection a plane and sphere.

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems

Given sphere with equation $x^2+y^2+z^2=100$, and plane $x=5$, describe the intersection of these two surfaces.

I understand that I could plugin $5$ for $x$. However, this yields a cylinder that does not describe the specific circle. How do I write the equation of this circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of a single equation in the variables $x,y,z$ is typically a surface, not a curve.

The circle in question can be represented algebraically using the system of two equations
$$
y^2+z^2=75,\;\;\;x=5
$$
or alternatively, in parametric form
\begin{align*}
x&=5\\[4pt]
y&=5\sqrt{3}\cos(t)\\[4pt]
z&=5\sqrt{3}\sin(t)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
for $0\le t < 2\pi$.

It's possible to represent the circle in question as the graph in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the single equation
$$
(x-5)^2+(y^2+z^2-75)^2=0
$$
but such a representation is not very useful.